# Partly dump SQL Server data (by limiting amount of dumped rows from each table)

Tags: sql-server, database, dump

Is there a way to dump only some portion of a SQL Server database, like if you have huge database with lots of tables and data in them?

Dumping it all will be time consuming and not needed. So my idea is just get some let's say 20 rows from each table. Is that somehow possible? Not doing that by hand.
Desired result in sql file:

```
A) db structure; 
B) data from each db table (20 rows).
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say dump, I interpret that as an equivalency to deleting. However, context seems to imply you've chosen a vernacular that equates dumping to retrieving. If I'm understanding your request correctly, you can use `information_schema` to pull known tables from a given DB.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       'select top 20 * from ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: By dump is meant [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_dump). Select only shows information.

Answer (score 0):

Used Data Pump for SQL Server from [DevArt](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/data-pump/), it did exactly what was needed.